# SQL Server CASE using 2 different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to use two different tables in a CASE statement but am really struggling.  Most of my SQL knowledge is self taught so finding it a bit of a struggle!

The result I am trying to achieve is if TC.ClockingStatus WHEN 1 then '24' (*1st Table*) if not WHEN OP.Status WHEN 'C' THEN 99 WHEN 'I' THEN 50 ELSE 0 END (*2nd Table*) AS Status.

This is my current statement:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    RTRIM(OP.Standard_Op) AS TaskDescription, 
    OP.Op_Number AS OpStep, 
    CAST(CAST(OP.Works_Order_Number AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS OrderCode, 
    CASE OP.Status 
       WHEN 'C' THEN 99 
       WHEN 'I' THEN 50 
       ELSE 0 
    END AS Status, 
    CAST(OP.Op_Number AS varchar(50)) AS OpCode, 
    CAST(CAST(OP.Works_Order_Number AS decimal(12, 2)) AS nvarchar(50)) + '_' + CAST(OP.Op_Number AS nvarchar(50)) AS JobCode, 
    TC.ClockingStatus
FROM         
    dbo.PROGRESS AS OP 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.vOrcData_ActiveOperations AS AW ON AW.Works_Order = OP.Works_Order_Number 
                                        AND AW.Op_Number = OP.Op_Number 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.WOHEAD AS WH ON WH.Works_Order = OP.Works_Order_Number 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.RESOURCE AS RR ON RR.Resource_Code = OP.Original_Resource_Code 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Techman_WOCLOCK AS TC ON OP.Works_Order_Number = TC.OrderCode 
                              AND OP.Op_Number = TC.OpStep 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.MEMO_FIELDS_SQL ON dbo.MEMO_FIELDS_SQL.Memo_Unique = OP.Man_Memo_Unique 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT     
         Allocated_WO_Num, Sub_Con_Op_No, 
         MAX(Date_Promised) AS Date_Promised
     FROM          
         dbo.PODETAIL AS PODETAIL_1
     GROUP BY 
         Allocated_WO_Num, Sub_Con_Op_No) AS PODETAIL ON PODETAIL.Allocated_WO_Num = OP.Works_Order_Number 
                                                      AND PODETAIL.Sub_Con_Op_No = OP.Op_Number 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT     
         Works_Order, Operation, 
         SUM(Operation_Time) AS TimeComplete
     FROM          
         dbo.WOCLOCK
     GROUP BY 
         Works_Order, Operation) AS CLOCKEDTIME ON WH.Works_Order = CLOCKEDTIME.Works_Order AND OP.Op_Number = CLOCKEDTIME.Operation
```

Comment: Tag your specific sql language

Comment: This is unreadable. Reduce the amount of code you have to show a simplified version of your problem.

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If you've joined the tables, there is no issue using both in the same CASE statement. Most likely you've got a syntax error somewhere. You should try to replicate the issue with a simplified query. If it persists, update the question with sample data, the query you wrote, the error message, and the result you want to achieve. If it doesn't, find and fix the syntax error in your original query.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use different columns/expressions in a case statement,
but you can't name the column before the first `WHEN`, like you do.

Try this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN TC.ClockingStatus = 1 THEN 24
    WHEN OP.Status = 'C' THEN 99
    WHEN OP.Status = 'I' THEN 50
    ELSE 0 END
```

The expressions inside a `WHEN` test can be as complicated as you like. You can even nest `CASE` statements:

```
CASE 
    WHEN TC.ClockingStatus = 1 THEN 24        
    ELSE CASE OP.Status 
        WHEN 'C' THEN 99
        WHEN 'I' THEN 50
        ELSE 0
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are trying to use the `CASE` form:

```
CASE <Field> WHEN <Value> THEN <Result>
```

What you need to use is the form:

```
CASE WHEN <Any condition no matter how complicated> THEN <Result>
```

Example:

```
CASE OP.Status WHEN 'C' THEN 99 ELSE 0 END
```

Can also be used as:

```
CASE WHEN OP.Status='C' THEN 99 ELSE 0 END
```